# Installing Windows 10 on a 2nd hard drive with Linux on the 1st hard drive

Tags: boot, usb, windows, uefi

I installed Linux on my computer on a new hard drive (I'll call this HDD1). I also have an existing hard drive(HDD2) on which I am trying to install Windows 10 (so far without success). I present the steps I took below:
1) I downloaded a Windows 10 ISO file (actually 4 separate files)
2) Clicking these files produced a dialogue box titled "Restore disc image" which allowed me to "restore" them to a USB stick.
3) This USB stick now contains the following directories:

boot
efi
sources
support

and the following standalone files:

autorun.inf
bootmgr
bootmgr.efi
setup.exe

Attempts to boot from this USB stick have so far proved unsuccessful. I have changed the boot priority (the UEFI manager lists 4 options) but the UEFI manager just reverts the order to Linux Ubuntu at no. 1 (in fact, none of the other options in the boot priority manager are even recognisable as "USB stick" - this is not really relevant though because I have tried every one of the 4 options without success).

I have also tried to install "Unetbootin" which apparently converts the files to make a bootable USB stick. However, when I try to run it returns an error message:

**Failed to run /usr/bin/unetbootin 'rootcheck=no' as user root.
Unable to copy the user's Xauthorization file.**

I am quite new to Linux and would therefore appreciate helpful comments aimed at a novice rather than a power user. Thank you

Comment: Windows resets the USB hubs during boot. It has to be specially modified in order to boot from USB. Is it possible to make a CD/DVD instead of a USB?

Comment: No. For some reason, when I click on destination in the dialogue box titled "Restore disc image" the option for CD/ DVD is greyed out. I cannot figure out why because Nautilus recognises the DVD disc drive as does the UEFI manager.

Comment: I assume there is a blank disk in the drive.

Comment: yes there is a blank DVD +R disc in the drive

Comment: do you have CD burning software installed?

Comment: No. What is the best CD burning software for Linux systems?

Comment: brasero is pretty good, it should be in the repository `sudo apt-get install brasero`

Comment: I have now burnt the contents of the USB stick to a DVD but it still didn't work

Comment: Not sure if this matters for windows but secure boot is off?

Comment: By following the instructions at the following site: https://venturebeat.com/2016/01/04/how-to-create-a-bootable-windows-10-usb-flash-drive-2/ I managed to create a bootable USB stick. However when I try to install it on my 2nd hard drive it refuses to recognise that same drive. I have reformatted the drive (and lost all the files on it as a result) but to no avail. How can I get the Windows installation package on my USB stick to recognise the hard drive I am trying to install to?

Comment: Window 10  requires GPT partitioning for EFI.